# How can I get a link to data from a JSON server in React?

Tags: reactjs, json

When I open a React project in one device (which is running in another), it does not receive data from the JSON server since the data is stored in the address localhost:3001/data. But you can open the main page, that is, localhost:3000. In another device, I opened a project with the IP of the device in which react was running. This is 192.168.1.5:3000. But you can’t do that with JSON. Now how to transfer data to the device in which the react application is opened?

I tried this

```
import axios from "axios"

export const DataService = {
    async getAll() {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/data')

        return response.data
    }
}
```

And on the page where I need to display the data I received it

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() => {
            const data = await DataService.getAll()
            setData(data)
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

And launched the JSON server and react. Everything works in the PC itself, because it receives all the data from its local storage, and if this project is opened in another device, that device will not receive it. And now the question is: how to get them in another device?

Comment: Change the AJAX operation to use the host's address instead of `localhost`?  `localhost` always references the current ("local") computer.